# APN Device Token for Multiple Users

Tags: ios9, devicetoken, apn, multiple-users

I have read apple's push notification guideline and a few stack overflow questions such as these:

- [APNs duplicate tokens](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11519435/apns-duplicate-tokens)
- [Are push notification tokens unique across all apps for a single device?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2751481/are-push-notification-tokens-unique-across-all-apps-for-a-single-device)
- [What Happen If a APNS Device Token Expired?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19782470/what-happen-if-a-apns-device-token-expired)
- [Does the APNS device token ever change, once created?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6652242/does-the-device-token-ever-change-once-created)

and even considered using google's GSM but realized underlaying it uses APN

- [Google/Apple Push Notification Service (APNS/GCM)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20685560/google-apple-push-notification-service-apns-gcm)
- [Is there any reason to use Google GCM vs Apple messaging for push notifications?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31661205/is-there-any-reason-to-use-google-gcm-vs-apple-messaging-for-push-notifications)

but none point out what happens when there are ***multiple users created for an app on the same device*** or when ***one user has multiple devices***. And only the question "Are push notification tokens unique across all apps for a single device?" addressed the multiple devices case but the answer was 5 years ago, so was wondering if anything changed with `iOS 9`.

Does that mean my server(provider) will have have a one to many relationship with a token and the primary key will constitute a `user_id`and a `user_token`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the reading material linked in the question, and Apple's documentation that the token may change, the `user_id` and `user_token` will have a `many-to-many` relationship and we should use Apple APN feedback service to remove old tokens.